# PyQt5: QDoubleSpinBox does not allow negative numbers

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

for some strange reasons I have trouble making my QDoubleSpinBoxes accept negative values. I've changed the range accordingly but the minimum still remains at 0 (default value). I don't have any issues involving negative numbers with QSpinBoxes, though. I find this very odd and I really can't figure out the issue here...

For example:

```
self.setMinimum(1.175494e-38)
self.setValue(-1.0)
```

... would actually change to 0.0 instead...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum that you set:

```
self.setMinimum(1.175494e-38)
```

is an extremely small number close to zero but not less than. So you can't put a negative value when you minimum has not been set to a negative value. Try put a negative number your minimum function

Comment: Silly me, I actually forgot about that. Thank you!